# How are iTunes Connect rankings determined?

Tags: app-store, itunes, app-store-connect

One of my apps recently appeared on the "Top Reference" list on iTunes for iPad apps.

Is there a published note on how iTunes calculates this list? Is it sales only, or is it customer ranking, etc?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is judged be sales since I have seen 3 star apps appear at the top of lists in the App Store. Correct me if I'm wrong, but sales is the factor.

Comment: I also believe this is the case. I've seen horrible apps come up in "Top Reference" list.